# VS2008 Express: How to save as UTF-8 all files by default?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, utf-8, visual-studio-express

Is there any way to make Visual Studio 2008 Express store all the files as UTF-8 by default?

Thanks for your time.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new file inside VS it will be UTF8 by default, but if the file is already created by other enconding you have to "Save as", and then change the enconding by pressing the down arrow in the "Save" button, and then selecting "Save with enconding..."